# Disable User In All SF Environments/Orgs (Production and Sandbox)

Tags: administration, sandbox, user-management, user-admin, production

Anyone know of a clever way to disable **users who's left the company *in all* Orgs**?  In our particular case, one Production with several Sandboxes.

The closest I can come up with is to perhaps grab their UserID and set Active to False (essentially) to each Org using Excel Connection (which I use regularly) or Data Loader (blah).

I searched around and saw nothing about this.  Seems like something "everyone" would want to do at the Administration level, as people leave the company and have a valid login in one Production, seven Sandboxes, and some Admins may only disable their user in Production...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Restrict by IP

Profile restrictions can prevent the user from logging in through remote locations, and this setting copies on Sandbox refreshes. Very simple procedure to kick them off your network, and they'll be unable to log in.

### Force Single Sign On

If SSO is enabled, and forced through My Domain, you can stop them from logging in through test.salesforce.com. There's a small amount of work required to configure ADFS and Salesforce whenever you refresh a Sandbox, but it's only a few minutes of effort for peace of mind.

### Delegated Authentication

If you're using delegated authentication, saleforce.com calls a webservice of your choosing to authenticate users. If this webservice is tied to, for example, to Active Directory, simply shutting off their network access also eliminates their salesforce.com access simultaneously-- their license will be active, but they can't actually log in.

### Freezing

Similarly, you could build a tool to freeze a user across many orgs all at once. For larger orgs where this may be a fairly common occurrence, it would probably be worth investing resources into, especially if it's less expensive than the alternative (data leaks, legal liability, etc).

Comment: In order:    (IP) Agree though does not disble;  (SSO) no SSO in that particular instance (I no longer work there), but agree it could work;  (Auth) same as SSO, but would be useful if that situation existed;   (Freeze) building a tool - blah.   In my eternal quest to AVOID being anything above "gui" developer (versus Apex, etc), it's my hope always to avoid dev work - there is always outsourcing, but then I'm architecting usually.   I APPRECIATE THE IDEAS as they ar ALL valid.   ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in many different ways.

Personally I would use an ETL Tool like TalenD to sync the users between the Orgs. There is no exact description on how to sync users but the are a couple of posts containing further links which may help to give you a start:

- [Copy Opportunities with LineItems with TalenD](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47046/copy-opportunities-with-lineitems-with-talend)
- [Datamigration Salesforce to Salesforce with TalenD - Best Practice for Self-Referreces](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46939/datamigration-salesforce-to-salesforce-with-talend-best-practice-for-self-refe)

But of course you can also use dataloader or excel connector.