# In deployment records are not deployed

Tags: deployment

In deployment process I moved reports from sand box to production (using change sets). But in production I only view the report fields I am not able see those records. And also I deployed source object too.
Please explain?

Comment: are there any records in your Object in Production, meeting the conditions that you specified for those reports?

Comment: in object also not showing any records

Comment: Alright, Create some records in that object meeting the conditions that you specify in reports and try...

Comment: If you are thinking about the records created in the testing environment to get into the Production, then the answer is you cannot move the records created in an object to another environment using Changeset. Changeset can only move the object related things and etc.. but not the dummy records in it.

Comment: @Subhash is any other way to upload records using eclipse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you cannot move data from the Sandbox to the Production environment using Eclipse. You could use the dataloader or a free tool like Jitterbit to export and then import your data. For other ideas on how to move the data see this question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273/copy-production-data-to-developer-sandbox). The question asks about moving production data to the sandbox but the same applies for sandbox to production. Keep in mind the Salesforce Ids will not be the same in the two different environments so you will need to do something to deal with any child records, like using an external id.

Comment: Can you tell me how to map both salesforce ID's. I mean sand box and production

Comment: @Rajesh Easiest way would be to create an external Id on the parent obect and then when you insert the parent records set that Id field to the sandbox Id. Then insert the child record using the externalid to match them. Use a dataloader to do the imports, you should probably also clear out the externalid field when you are done since it's a one time update. I wrote a blog post awhile back on the opposite direction using jitterbit but the concept is the same, http://www.inthenimbus.com/index.php/2015/09/20/moving-production-data-to-a-sandbox/